# Exporting ArcMap produced layer file histogram?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, graph, histogram

I could simply take a screenshot, or reproduce it in other software, but what I see when I go to layer properties>symbology>classify is perfect for what I need.

The only thing is  it would be nice to have picture with better resolution, so I'm wondering if I could somehow export this graph. I have ArcMap Basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open table
2. Select Graph, type Hystogram
3. Pick field
   Experiment with graphs, there are options to export, etc